# Map of Massachusetts does not show counties in it in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-visualization

```
function createVis(errors, mapData, spendingData) {
var length = (mapData.features.length)-1;    
var width = 700;
var height = 580;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",width).attr("height", 
height);
var g = svg.append("g");

var projection = d3.geoConicConformal().scale(10000).parallels([41 + 17 / 
60, 41 + 29 / 60]).rotate([70 + 30 / 60, 0]).translate([600, 
320]).center([0, 41.313]);

var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

    g.selectAll("path")
    .data(mapData.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", "#ff4500")
    .attr("stroke", "#000000").
    attr("d", geoPath);

    }
```

This is my code and my data looks like:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "SCHOOLDISTRICTS_POLY",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ORG_CODE": "08280000", "DISTRICT": "Greater Lowell", "MADISTTYPE": "Regional Vocational Technical", "TOWN_REG": "REGIONAL", "STARTGRADE": "9", "ENDGRADE": "12", "SHAPE_AREA": 183340893.146, "SHAPE_LEN": 81197.948086200005 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -71.255132443929881, 42.73647401089648 ], [ -71.238178798293632, 42.669419453899359 ], [ -71.256187892779593, 42.657145166389917 ], [ -71.275154586332562, 42.65621644091356 ], [ -71.271188032661229, 42.644241513107872 ], [ -71.283427931805434, 42.615299997131757 ], [ -71.31930983289854, 42.613572526588307 ], [ -71.31989722336931, 42.606900823786113 ], [ -71.359942889463611, 42.625971844090664 ], [ -71.380686660171804, 42.648913650788081 ], [ -71.398995607356738, 42.652467306292387 ], [ -71.398890239389331, 42.644949295840014 ], [ -71.417642263054788, 42.653774259235455 ], [ -71.493527614175989, 42.617403520281393 ], [ -71.496484694790936, 42.649802940881621 ], [ -71.514968843946718, 42.643622718167784 ], [ -71.53441392920378, 42.648414608892729 ], [ -71.532408146338923, 42.668978233475208 ], [ -71.557414123221093, 42.676313626336444 ], [ -71.542436667347644, 42.702804614490802 ], [ -71.294870530970343, 42.697243338711019 ], [ -71.255132443929881, 42.73647401089648 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ORG_CODE": "08230000", "DISTRICT": "Greater Lawrence", "MADISTTYPE": "Regional Vocational Technical", "TOWN_REG": "REGIONAL", "STARTGRADE": "9", "ENDGRADE": "12", "SHAPE_AREA": 233855647.47099999, "SHAPE_LEN": 74299.8765288 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -71.114400587200862, 42.740129766717118 ], [ -71.040519483804715, 42.672687761947358 ], [ -71.022309620720165, 42.641636185283097 ], [ -71.054557785237776, 42.627652286486381 ], [ -71.058766177820033, 42.609077177266343 ], [ -71.135405198509417, 42.599079552340889 ], [ -71.154419482450422, 42.615267949580215 ], [ -71.164878523405847, 42.598021163816156 ], [ -71.182046196216064, 42.608446462192617 ], [ -71.171755925471757, 42.616545623433943 ], [ -71.256187892779593, 42.657145166389917 ], [ -71.238178798293632, 42.669419453899359 ], [ -71.255132443929881, 42.73647401089648 ], [ -71.223825731175651, 42.746486059440002 ], [ -71.181786155884325, 42.737341386734691 ], [ -71.182398057854201, 42.794329603021914 ], [ -71.130565074650804, 42.760751689240472 ], [ -71.114400587200862, 42.740129766717118 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ORG_CODE": "08050000", "DISTRICT": "Blackstone Valley", "MADISTTYPE": "Regional Vocational Technical", "TOWN_REG": "REGIONAL", "STARTGRADE": "9", "ENDGRADE": "12", "SHAPE_AREA": 661502879.97000003, "SHAPE_LEN": 116533.596546 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -71.674171757034856, 42.248590738019871 ], [ -71.650161498976374, 42.247791654310511 ], [ -71.644427357674218, 42.226626916611536 ], [ -71.621109872583972, 42.230868211504713 ], [ -71.599317787389609, 42.225959169161314 ], [ -71.602221146931029, 42.218101467011344 ], [ -71.582910569270638, 42.19555960086273 ], [ -71.556781683922011, 42.192450091473994 ], [ -71.555737563339704, 42.1825031786829 ], [ -71.502630265569763, 42.191413366176555 ], [ -71.497378082864216, 42.166642952706297 ], [ -71.478027457313758, 42.165870750276255 ], [ -71.478522477773666, 42.13137789839508 ], [ -71.441791667798881, 42.135231268493953 ], [ -71.458116158718354, 42.017852324644025 ], [ -71.79918763415759, 42.008053340823544 ], [ -71.830063886806272, 42.092777977411089 ], [ -71.797176835169878, 42.099171862669913 ], [ -71.8179527531221, 42.133265502868504 ], [ -71.829530455461665, 42.129390662327502 ], [ -71.824852663826263, 42.155332124555144 ], [ -71.83410521586049, 42.154990238577142 ], [ -71.825485424224823, 42.159920520690811 ], [ -71.831504222841104, 42.164253168060533 ], [ -71.79714018846586, 42.210039684592466 ], [ -71.731237079193022, 42.24128620665789 ], [ -71.674171757034856, 42.248590738019871 ] ] ] } }
```

This is just part of data. My JSON file has more data. By the code above I am able to get the state map of Massachusetts but however I am not able to see the boundaries of the counties in it. Can anyone help me in modifying my code in order to be able to see the boundaries of counties?

---

[This is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWgTn.png)
[But I am getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThdmQ.jpg)

Comment: Can you link to the full geojson at all?

Comment: d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://cdn.rawgit.com/dakoop/e3d0b2100c6b6774554dddb0947f2b67/raw/ea38ad2f7949fb5c2242fa1571c9ea12140f2a76/ma-school-districts-500.geojson")
    .defer(d3.csv, "https://cdn.rawgit.com/dakoop/e3d0b2100c6b6774554dddb0947f2b67/raw/ea38ad2f7949fb5c2242fa1571c9ea12140f2a76/ma-school-funding.csv")
    .await(createVis);     I am using this to give a call to createVis

Comment: I am able to link to geoJson and I am getting a map of Massachusetts but without  the counties border

Comment: I have attached in the answer comment my output and expected one. It might help in understanding what I am trying to say. I think I am making some mistake in drawing boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph has all data what you need, its just not visible. If you change the "fill" attribute to "none". You'll can see it:

```
g.selectAll("path")
.data(mapData.features)
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("fill", "#ff4500")
.attr("stroke", "#000000")
.attr("d", geoPath)
```

change

```
g.selectAll("path")
.data(mapData.features)
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("fill", "none")       //   <--HERE
.attr("stroke", "#000000")
.attr("d", geoPath)
```

or better change opacity, so you can see where the problem is:

```
g.selectAll("path")
.data(mapData.features)
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("fill", "#ff45000A")       //   <--HERE #RRGGBBAA AA=alpha
.attr("stroke", "#000000")
.attr("d", geoPath)
```

more dark color .. more overlapping polygons

[image]

[image]

D3 draw path according its appears.

i.e. move "Hilltown Cooperative Charter Public" feature, at the first position (at this moment its 396th) and affter the others Districts. Basically revert the order they appears.-

```js
d3.queue()
 .defer(d3.json, "https://cdn.rawgit.com/dakoop/e3d0b2100c6b6774554dddb0947f2b67/raw/ea38ad2f7949fb5c2242fa1571c9ea12140f2a76/ma-school-districts-500.geojson")
  //.defer(d3.csv, "https://cdn.rawgit.com/dakoop/e3d0b2100c6b6774554dddb0947f2b67/raw/ea38ad2f7949fb5c2242fa1571c9ea12140f2a76/ma-school-funding.csv")
  .await(createVis);

function createVis(errors, mapData, spendingData) {
var length = (mapData.features.length)-1;    
var width = 700;
var height = 580;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",width).attr("height", 
height);
var g = svg.append("g");

var projection = d3.geoConicConformal().scale(10000).parallels([41 + 17 / 
60, 41 + 29 / 60]).rotate([70 + 30 / 60, 0]).translate([600, 
320]).center([0, 41.313]);

var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

    g.selectAll("path")
    .data(mapData.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", "#ff45001F")
    .attr("stroke", "#000000")
    .attr("d", geoPath)
    .attr("id",function(d){return d.properties.ORG_CODE;});

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**SOLUTION**

**Draw county with fill none and dashed strokes, and district with the color range from ma-school-funding.csv, without stroke.-**

Comment: Thank you so much that was really helpful!!  One more thing what difference did it make in the previous code where we just changed fill   to .attr("fill", "#ff45000A")  and  .attr("id",function(d){return d.properties.ORG_CODE;}) . Why did we use ORG_CODE?

Comment: Ooh. I have used to give an unique ID to each polygon to determine which one I'm seeing. A little trick. You can safe remove it. :D